# Is it possible to get channel ID by name in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

The title says it all...
I want to get the channel id given a specific name in a guild, but I could not find anything in the documentation that lets me do that. Looking at more developed bots like [Mee6](https://mee6.xyz/), they have the option to connect to your server and set a welcome page for any of your text channels. I've tried something like:

```
channels = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), guild__name='Test Server'
```

But this only returns 'Text Channels' and nothing else.

Comment: I don't understand.  Is this running as part of a command?  If you have the guild you can do `get(guild.channels, name="channel name")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What Abdulaziz said is correct but is less efficient and lengthier, you can use [utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=given_name)
channel_id = channel.id
```

Comment: where does the 'ctx' come from. I assume it is from discord.ext? What else can you use, if ctx is not available?

Comment: It is a context object, you can get its access inside a command or you can do `client.get_all_channels()` instead of `ctx.guild.channels`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't specifically know what server you are looking through to get the channel, you could use this:

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(self.client.get_all_channels(), id=channel_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name=name_channel)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `discord.ext.commands` you can do a loop like this.

```py
@bot.command()
async def get_channel(ctx, *, given_name=None):
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        if channel.name == given_name:
            wanted_channel_id = channel.id

    await ctx.send(wanted_channel_id) # this is just to check
```

Answer (score -5):

channel = message.channel

Simple