# Can't delete discord channel using its name as the variable for the name is causing nonetype error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command that takes an input and is meant to then delete a channel based of that input for a ticket system. The command can now delete the channel however the delete method doesn't recognise the "output" variable.

I am new to discordpy, sorry in advance.

```
if message.content.startswith(".close"):
        verify_channel = client.get_channel(756238816511131773)
        if not message.channel.id == verify_channel.id:
            await message.delete()
        else:
            msg = message.content.split()
            output = ""
            for word in msg[1:]:
                output += word
                output += " "
        
       guild = message.guild
            channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name=output)
            await channel.delete()
```

Error  being produced when running the command:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get channel ID by name in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321098/is-it-possible-to-get-channel-id-by-name-in-discord-py)

Comment: Almost but the channel name is determined by the variable "output" and the new issue seems to be that "output" isn't working when searching for channel names and the command will have different channel names each time so I cant use a default channel name

Comment: Then edit your question to what you actually want, since what you asked is `is there a method of getting the channel ID from the name of the channel`, create a new question if you have some other problem unrelated to this question.

Comment: I updated the question, ty

Comment: There's a problem in your original code/question I didn't notice while writing my answer, but output isn't declared before the `else` statement so it will be out of scope and therefore `None` by the time `discord.utils.get()` gets called. The function will fail to find the None channel and return `None`.

Comment: Good point, how would I fix that as the output has to be defined once the channel is checked from the if statement

Comment: Please refrain from editing your question to completely something else after you get a few answers. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions, stackoverflow is not a forum

Comment: I'm going to disregard that comment, but thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working code that uses channel mentions. Mentions in chat look like this: `I'm mentioning a channel: #ghi` where `ghi` is a channel name. If you print that out, it converts #ghi to `<#622194268139683870>`. You could extract this with regex or something but you can also call a function on the message:

```
channel = message.channel_mentions[0] #Only use the first channel mentioned
await channel.delete()
```

Here's a working example converted to a command, which I recommend over starting every function with `if startswith(command_name)`

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@bot.command()
async def close(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.channel_mentions[0]
    await channel.delete()
    print("Success")
```

You can then invoke from chat like `.close #ghi`

**JUST MAKE SURE YOU ADD THIS TO THE TOP OF YOUR ON_MESSAGE EVENT IF YOU INTEND TO KEEP IT**

```
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

I have tested, it works.

---

P.S.:
Commands also have the advantage of easily getting parameters instead of splitting strings by spaces, I can't explain right now but I recommend the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

I didn't include this because your function can be written without it.

Comment: That is a much better solution and I thought it would of worked however when I run .close #ticket-xxxx in chat nothing happens, the console doesn't even seem to recognise it running

Comment: I just edited my answer, check again for the section under the bold sentence. It involves a special line to add to your on_message event.

Comment: Hi i had a look, but i prefer the command option its a lot simpler, so i tried removing the on_message version but the command version just doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: @max Your `on_message` is blocking the command. Either remove it, or add `await bot.process_commands(message)` under your `on_message` like @Allister mentioned.

Comment: yeah i completely removed the on_message version

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you add a print statement to the command to see if its getting invoked at all?

Comment: yeah i tried a basic command that it is .test and it should just print "test" to the console and its not doing that ```@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print("test")```

Comment: Works for me, how do you define `client`?

Comment: I changed client to bot just incase it was that but it now looks like this ```bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")```

Comment: Can you upload your entire file (token excluded) to pastebin for me?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0CcDby5n everything else works such as .ticket and .verify just commands for some reason

Comment: You didn't delete the on_message event like you said you had. Delete it or add the `await bot.process_commands(message)` line like i showed

Comment: oh i thought you meant the specific .close on_message event, I am so sorry but thank you so much!!! is there any kind of commendation on stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a channel object by it's name by using [`get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(".close"):
        guild = message.guild
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="channel_name")
        await channel.delete()
```

Comment: that concept seems like it would work however "channel_name" keeps returning None when i change it to output (another variable which should be a channels name). ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'``` ```channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name=output)```

Comment: Are you using  `.close` in the ticket channel? I'm assuming it's a command to close a ticket, and by closing the ticket you're trying to delete the channel?

Comment: .close isnt used in the ticket channel its self as the command has to have a filter to ensure it isnt used in any other channels(such as a member in general), so therefore it has a specific channel it can only be used in

Comment: What does `print(output)` return?

Comment: it returns "ticket-4393" which is the text channel I entered. The whole command would be ".close ticket-4393"

Comment: Instead of putting `output` in `name=` try putting `str(output)`

Comment: still the same error, i think it hsa something to do with https://stackoverflow.com/users/12514997/allister answer about when output is defined